# To use javac bootclasspath do i need everything in jre/lib or just rt.jar?

Tags: java

When trying to compile targeting java 5 from java 7 and I set the bootclasspath parameters all the examples I see just need the rt.jar from the jre/lib directory. I don't see any errors at all and it seems to work, but just to be sure, will having a folder with only the rt.jar inside would be enough? Or do i need the complete lib folder?

Comment: Surely you can try this yourself by making a quick modification to the commands/scripts you are using :) Just saying! Do post your findings please; I am interested in knowing the answer to this question.

Comment: Yeah i have tried it just pointing to the rt.jar file and it seems to work, there is no apparent issue and no warnings, but I reaally got to be sure about this or else my boss will cut my nuts.

Comment: How are you doing this ? Are you using eclipse or someother Id ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can answer my own question, it appears that most common applications will build with just rt.jar but my application requiered jce.jar too to be able to compile so i could say that yes indeed sometimes you will need more than rt.jar, and maybe too the ext directory.